# Abort certain edit events

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3, arcfm

ArcMap 9.3.1 w/ ArcFM.  Using C#.

The goal is to be able to prevent certain edits based on specified business rules.

One option might seem to be looking at all operation edits in BeforeStopEditing and somehow cancelling the operation here.  This is not possible as ESRI states you can't call AbortOperation here and throwing an exception does not prevent the operation from committing.  Even setting a flag in BeforeStopEditing and calling UndoOperation in StopEditing if the flag is set won't work.

The obvious documented approach is to create a custom class extension and apply to all (required) tables.  A given table can only have one class extension applied.  Since we are using ArcFM it has applied its class extension(s) to the feature class tables.  We could probably use this approach for the data tables.

We are currently using the Editor IEditEvents* to listen for feature edits, but this doesn't provide data table edits.

We are also hoping to avoid applying a custom class extension to 100's of tables, the maintenence group would not agree to that.

It's also not feasible to get all IObjectClasses and listen to each directly in the code.

The hope was to find an existing coclass or interface that broadcasts edit events for all tables.  The doc's seem to suggest ObjectClassEvents may do this, but only in VB.  Trying to create an instance of this in C# throws an exception (factory can't create).

Suggestions ?

Comment: Version 9.3.1 is a bit old. Are you just looking for edits as a part of an edit session or field calculations also? What is your workspace you want to 'protect'? fGDB, SDE.. Have a look at http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/ArcObjects/ao_start.htm and http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/arcobjects/esrigeodatabase/iversionevents.htm (SDE Only)

Comment: We want to prevent edits during an edit session to an SDE workspace.  I don't think IVersionEvents could be used to solve this, we want to prevent at the operation or store level, not reconcile.

Comment: How do you define a 'good' edit and a 'bad' edit? I am fairly sure that if you know how to decide you can use your underlying database to reject an edit... using IEditWorkspace you can get the features modified, make a decision and then call undo if you don't like them.

Comment: We are trying to create a framework to support configurable biz rules on what edits are allowed, that parrt isn't a problem.  the problem is getting the edit event and being able to cancel it.  
As mentioned we did try using undo based on the operation edits found in BeforeStopEditing but calling it from StopEditing doesn't work, it causes memory corruption.

Comment: IEditor.StopEditing(False); causes memory corruption? You should really be looking at OnStopOperation then validate and undo or AbortOperation - a edit session could contain some valid edits and some invalid.. that doesn't help with functions that don't call StartOperation. However SDE edits on a *versioned workspace must be contained within an edit operation*. That's quite a conundrum, as you have the business rules, Editor validations, SDE validations all mixed up. Trying to idiot proof your system may just lead to a better class of idiot - education may be better than code in this case.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the last thing we tried was listen for BeforeStopOperation, get all edits in the operation, if any are invalid display dialog to user, then set a flag saying we need to undo.  We then also listened for OnStopOperation and tried calling UndoOperation if the flag was set - that is what causes memory corruption and crashing.

Comment: Yes, in a perfect world education would be enough.  The client has been clear that we don't live in a perfect world.  :)  I think I might just have to be clear that there is a tech solution (class extension for the data tables), but it will involve touching the config for all those tables, and let them decide if it's worth it.